# How to get an array from an array of arrays (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am receiving this when i use print_r:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 15 
    [1] => 15 
    [2] => 15 
    [3] => 15 
    [4] => 15 
    [5] => 16 
    [6] => 15 
    [7] => 15 
    [8] => 15 
    [9] => 14 
    ... and so on ... 
)
```

and I was wondering how I can get an array of these second values (i.e.):

```
$newArray = array(15,15,15,15,15,16,15,15,15,14, ... );
```

I have tried using array_values but to no avail!

As a background, I got these results from a single column in my database and am now trying to plot them using HighRoller/HighCharts.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have an array of arrays. You have an array of values with numeric indexes. Unless I am totally misunderstanding your question ....

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 15 
    [1] => 15 
    [2] => 15 
    [3] => 15 
    [4] => 15 
    [5] => 16 
    [6] => 15 
    [7] => 15 
    [8] => 15 
    [9] => 14 
    ... and so on ... 
)
```

This means your array at index 0 has value 15 and so on.

Comment: thank you very much for the help - silly misunderstanding on my behalf and was confused by the print_r output

Comment: Personally I like to use var_export over print_r since var_export will always print whatever you give it exactly. It's great for dealing with weak typed objects like bools/ints/strings as well as arrays and objects.

Answer (score 0):

the "second values" are the values of the array... the square bracket numbers are the indexes. you simply access them with `$array_name[0]` or `$array_name[5]` or `foreach($array_name as $idx => $val) echo($val);`

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, what you are showing is not a multi-dimensional array.

A multi-dimensional array would look something like this when var_dumped

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    int(15)
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    int(15)
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    int(15)
  }
}
```

To answer the question even though it doesn't look like what you have, for each level of a multi-dimensional array you can use an embedded foreach() loop.

```
<?php

$myArray = [
    [15],
    [15],
    [15],

];

var_dump($myArray);//outputs above example

foreach($myArray as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $val) {
        echo $val;//outputs the value of each array inside the outer array
    }
}
```